# Import vector graphics from Flash to Flash Builder

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I'm a new to mobile apps development, so sorry for such a silly question.

I have a scene made in Adobe Flash (saved as FLA). There is no Action Script, just a vector drawing.

So now, I'm developing an application for iOS/Android ("Mobile Flex Application" in Adobe Flash Builder) and I need to use that drawing.

I've been searching how to do that for a few hours, tried to export my drawing as SWC and FXG files - but nothing worked in Flash Builder.

So, how can I import it into Flash Builder?

Show me the way please!

Comment: You can use the [Embed] metadata tag to [Embed FXG graphics in Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstarts/embedding_assets.edu.html#UsingFXGDocuments). I prefer pure actionscript 3 projects in Flash Builder and I use .swc libraries. It's just a matter of adding them to the build path(via **project settings > Flex Build Path > Library Path > Add SWC**), something like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/images/flex_addSwc.png). The nice thing about it this is the assets exported for Actionscript in the swc will appear in the autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed swfs like so:

```
[Embed(source="path/to/my.swf")]
[Bindable]
public var swfCls:Class;
```

then in mxml, use a SWFLoader to display it:

```
<s:SWFLoader source="{swfCls}" />
```

Comment: yes, but there is a strange thing: whole swf doesn't work but if i embed symbols from it - [Embed(source="assets/5f10bf76b5.swf", symbol="diffright")] - it works!